# JavaFX Vertical Tabs with Horizontal Text

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm stuck on some css and I'm not sure which classes I need to target to achieve what I want.

I have a `TabPane` on the left side of my window. I have rotated the graphics and set a button with it's own graphics to act as a tab label with graphics. The problem is, i'd like to left align it and I can't seem to find a way to. Here's what my UI looks like:

[image: This is what my UI looks like]

I'd like to left align it. How can I go about it?

Here's my code:

```
<TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" rotateGraphic="true" side="LEFT" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
            <tabs>
                <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1" >
                    <graphic>
                        <JFXButton fx:id="tab" text="Dashboard" styleClass="tab-button" >
                            <graphic>
                                <FontIcon iconLiteral="fltral-home-20"/>
                            </graphic>
                        </JFXButton>
                    </graphic>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2"/>
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
```

And the Css:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab > .tab-container > .tab-label {
    -fx-rotate: 90;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-min-height: 15em; 
    -fx-tab-max-height: -fx-tab-min-height:; 
    -fx-tab-min-width: 3em; 
    -fx-tab-max-width: -fx-tab-min-width; 
}
```

Comment: See if any ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61284133/how-can-i-mirror-the-tab-in-the-given-code/61284479#61284479) will help.

Comment: @Sedrick setting the button Padding to 0 helps, but its still not at the left